# Mysql order by RAND, but must include few data

Tags: mysql

I am facing some unusual issue. Please help. There are 300 rows in a column. I want to display any 100 order by rand(). But within this randomly selected 100, there must be 2 rows. How can I write it?
Example:

"Select id from sample_table where id<300 or id>1 order by rand() limit 100"

But I want the result must include id=34 and id=78

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UNION ALL to select the 2 rows that must exist in the results and 98 random rows:

```
select id from sample_table 
where id in (34, 78) 
union all
select id from (
  select id from sample_table 
  where where id not in (34, 78)
  order by rand() limit 98
) t
order by rand()
```

or simpler with conditional sorting:

```
select * from (
  select id from sample_table 
  order by id not in (34, 78), rand()
  limit 100
) t
order by rand()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. But I want this 34 and 78 is mixed with the rest id randomly. The result either starts with 34,78 or ends with 34,78.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know. What is this 't'?

Comment: t is the alias of the subquery. Mysql requires every subquery aliased.

Comment: Thanks. It worked exactly like I wanted. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Union both to the original SELCT and random the result of that union

```
SELECT 
    id
FROM
    (SELECT 34 UNION SELECT 78 UNION SELECT 
        id
    FROM
        sample_table
    WHERE
        id < 300 OR id > 1
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 98)
ORDER BY RAND()
```